# ¿Por qué me hace remove en una lista que no estoy llamando?

Tags: python, python-3.x

El código a continuación es un trozo de una función en la que estoy trabajando.
Al principio del programa cuento con una lista de letras llamada "myTiles" y una palabra "word".

Mi objetivo es cada vez que encuentro una letra de "word" en "myTiles" es quitarla, para después comprobar que hay suficientes letras "myTiles" para la "word" indicada.

Como no quiero perder las letras de "myTiles" cada vez que se encuentra un elemento, estoy usando otra variable llamada "temp_tiles" que se iguala a "myTiles" inicialmente, y es la variable que usaré para ir haciendo .remove() y así no perder el valor de "myTiles".

Mi problema es que pese a solo hacer temp_tiles.remove(letter), también me borra la letra en la lista "myTiles".

```
myTiles = ['T','Y','S','E','U','W','I'] 
word = 'SWET'

temp_tiles = myTiles

for letter in word:
    if letter in temp_tiles:
        temp_tiles.remove(letter)

    else:
        valid = False   # No hacer caso a esta línea, valid es una variable que uso en el código que estoy trabajando

print(myTiles)
print(temp_tiles)
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando dices

```
temp_tiles = myTiles
```

no estás creando una copia de la lista `myTiles`; simplemente dices que `temp_tiles` y `myTiles` son dos referencias a una misma lista. O sea, dos nombres distintos e intercambiables para la misma cosa. Si haces algo con un nombre, se ve reflejado en el otro.

Si quieres tener una copia de la lista que sea completamente separada, tienes que crear una nueva lista copiando elemento por elemento. Para simplificarlo existe el método `copy()`

```
temp_tiles = myTiles.copy()
```

que hace exactamente lo antedicho.

#### Demo

```
myTiles = ['T','Y','S','E','U','W','I']
word = 'SWET'

temp_tiles = myTiles.copy()

for letter in word:
    if letter in temp_tiles:
        temp_tiles.remove(letter)

    else:
        valid = False   # No hacer caso a esta línea, valid es una variable que uso en el código que estoy trabajando

print(myTiles)
print(temp_tiles)
```

produce

```
['T', 'Y', 'S', 'E', 'U', 'W', 'I']
['Y', 'U', 'I']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: *tienes que crear una nueva lista copiando elemento por elemento. Para simplificarlo existe el método copy()* - copy no copia el contenido de la lista, solo copia la lista en sí.

Answer (score 1):

#### Variables y referencias

Las variables no almacenan objetos, si no REFERENCIAS a objetos. Es decir, se guarda la ubicación de ese objeto en una especie de "cache".

Podríamos decir que una variable es un "nombre" que le damos a un objeto.

Cuando haces, por ejemplo, `a = b` el valor de b NO se copia, si no que lo que se copia es la referencia. Por lo tanto, en realidad, ambas variables referencian al mismo objeto.

Este fenomeno podríamos decir que resulta en a siendo un "alias" de b. Es decir, otro nombre para referirse a lo mismo.

Recuerda, **las variables son nombres que le das a las cosas, no contenedores**
.

#### Viendo tu código

Entonces, resulta que, debido a la asignación:

```
temp_tiles = myTiles
```

En realidad, tanto temp_tiles como myTiles se tratan de la misma lista. Por eso cambiar la lista desde una variable releja el cambio en la otra.

#### Solución para el escenario actual

Podés crear una nueva lista con el contenido de la original haciendo `myTiles.copy()`, tal como dice Candid en su respuesta.

#### Por que copy no siempre sirve

Pero copy solo copia la lista. Mas no su contenido. copy crea una nueva referencia o nombre a los objetos que tenía la lista anterior.

Entonces, por ejemplo, el siguiente código:

```
lista_de_dicts = [{}]
otra_lista = lista_de_dicts.copy()

otra_lista[0]["hola"] = 0
otra_lista.append({})

print("original", lista_de_dicts)
print("copia", otra_lista)
```

En el cual, se evidencia que el diccionario en la lista original no se copió. Ya que esto produce:

```
original [{'hola': 0}]
copia [{'hola': 0}, {}]
```

Pero como la lista si fue copiada, añadir algo a otra_lista no afecta a listas_de_dicts.

Para eso, deberás copiar recursivamente el contenido. Esto lo hace [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), que tiene un excelente algoritmo.

#### Cuando hay que hacer una copia profunda

Generalmente, conviene hacer una copia profunda cuando el contenido de la lista es [mutable](https://docs.python.org/es/3/glossary.html#term-mutable), es decir, que se pueden modificar "in-place". Por ejemplo las sublistas y las clases escritas en Python son mutables.

Por el contrario, los objetos [inmutables](https://docs.python.org/es/3/glossary.html#term-immutable), no requieren ser copiados, por que al no poder ser modificados, no surgirá ningun comportamiento inesperado. Por ejemplo, cuando concatenas una cadena, en realidad estás creando una cadena nueva.