# ¿En Python se puede hacer la segunda llamada a la función SeleccionarElementos(ventana) cuando termine la primera llamada?

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, menu, funcion

El siguiente es un ejemplo reducido de un código más complejo.
En este ejercicio se trata de seleccionar dos veces los elementos de una lista.  El problema es que al invocar el comando SeleccionarDosVeces, ejecuta las dos llamadas a la función SeleccionarElementos(ventana) sin esperar a que termine la primera llamada, de modo que la segunda selección tiene una lista vacía.
Si bien puedo resolver este problema considerando dos opciones en el menú (por ejemplo PrimeraSeleccion y  SegundaSeleccion), la idea es que se realice de una vez, porque en el programa real tendría que considerar muchas opciones.

¿Existe alguna forma para que la segunda llamada a la función SeleccionarElementos(ventana) espere a que termine la primera llamada?

De esta forma la solución tiene algunas restricciones:

- No agregar otra opción en la barra menú.
- No limitar el tiempo que tiene el usuario para seleccionar.
- En lo posible no modificar la función SeleccionarElementos(ventana)

El código es el siguiente:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    class ListaEntrada():
        def __init__(self, atributo1, atributo2):
            self.mensaje = atributo1
            self.lista = atributo2
        def limpiar(self):
            self.mensaje = ""
            self.lista = []
    
    class ListaSalida():
        def __init__(self, atributo1, atributo2):
            self.lista = atributo1
            self.indice = atributo2
        def limpiar(self):
            self.lista = []
            self.indice = []
    
    def SeleccionarElementos(ventana):
        mensaje = lista_entrada.mensaje
        lista = lista_entrada.lista
    
        def seleccionar():
            lista_salida.limpiar()
            for i in range(len(lista)):
                if var_list[i].get() == 1:
                    lista_salida.lista.append(lista[i])
                    lista_salida.indice.append(i)
            limpiar_ventana()
    
        def limpiar_ventana():
            etiqueta.pack_forget()
            for checkbox in checkboxes:
                checkbox.pack_forget()
            boton_continuar.pack_forget()
    
        etiqueta = tk.Label(ventana, text=mensaje)
        etiqueta.pack()

        var_list = []
        checkboxes = []
        for elemento in lista:
            var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
            var_list.append(var)
            checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(ventana, text=elemento, variable=var)
            checkbox.pack(pady=1, anchor=tk.W)
            checkboxes.append(checkbox)
        boton_continuar = tk.Button(ventana, text="Continuar", command=seleccionar)
        boton_continuar.pack()

        return 

    def SeleccionarDosVeces(ventana): 
        SeleccionarElementos(ventana) 
        lista_entrada.mensaje = "Seleccione otra vez"
        lista_entrada.lista = lista_salida.lista 
        SeleccionarElementos(ventana) 
    
    def MenuPrincipal(): 
        ventana = tk.Tk()
        ventana.geometry("800x500+20+20")
        ventana.title("Selecciona en listas")
        barra_menu=tk.Menu(ventana)
        menu_1 = tk.Menu(barra_menu,tearoff=False,)
        barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Menu",  menu=menu_1)
        menu_1.add_command(
            label="Seleccionar dos veces", 
            command= lambda: SeleccionarDosVeces(ventana)
            )
        menu_1.add_separator()
        menu_1.add_command(
            label="Salir", 
            command=ventana.destroy
            )
        ventana.configure(menu=barra_menu)
        ventana.mainloop()
        return  
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        lista_vacia = []
        lista_entrada = ListaEntrada("Primera Seleccion", ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"])
        lista_salida  = ListaSalida(lista_vacia, lista_vacia)
        MenuPrincipal()
        print(lista_salida.lista, lista_salida.indice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacer que la segunda llamada espere a SeleccionarElementos a que termine la primera. Algunas opciones:

Usar una variable de control boolena:

```
seleccion_terminada = False

def SeleccionarElementos(ventana):
  # código de selección
  
  global seleccion_terminada 
  seleccion_terminada = True

def SeleccionarDosVeces(ventana):

  SeleccionarElementos(ventana)

  while not seleccion_terminada:
    time.sleep(0.1)

  seleccion_terminada = False
  
  SeleccionarElementos(ventana)
```

Usar un candado:

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

def SeleccionarElementos(ventana):
  # código de selección

  lock.release()

def SeleccionarDosVeces(ventana):

  lock.acquire()
  SeleccionarElementos(ventana)
  lock.acquire()

  SeleccionarElementos(ventana)
```

Usar una cola:

```
from queue import Queue

cola = Queue()

def SeleccionarElementos(ventana):
  # código de selección  

  cola.put(True)

def SeleccionarDosVeces(ventana):

  SeleccionarElementos(ventana)
  cola.get()
  
  SeleccionarElementos(ventana)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Llamadas

Lo normal en Python, y probablemente muchos otros lenguajes de programación, es que, si un programa choca con una llamada a una función, la ejecuta y "espera" a que termine (espera entre comillas por que en realidad se está encargando de ejecutar la función).

¿Entonces, por que "termina antes"? Bueno, en realidad, se comporta como es esperado, no termina antes. No hay nada indicando que la función deba esperar a la selección del usuario, por lo que finaliza y Python sigue ejecutando cosas.

##### Tkinter y "trabar" una función

En realidad, "trabar" el avance de una función esperando la selección del usuario, no es una opción. Lo unico que lograríamos es que se congele la interfaz.
Si estás familiarizado con pygame, te diría que tkinter también trabaja con un loop. Pero si no, te digo que Tkinter no es estatico, está repitiendo una y otra vez un código que se encarga de procesar eventos y redibujar de manera optimizada la ventana. Cuando una función se ejecuta, este loop no puede seguir avanzando hasta que termine, quitando a Tkinter la posibilidad de procesar eventos, como el clic del mouse.

#### Un punto aparte

Esto no tiene tanta relación, pero me llama la atención este fragmento de código:

```
lista_vacia = []
lista_entrada = ListaEntrada("Primera Seleccion", ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"])
lista_salida  = ListaSalida(lista_vacia, lista_vacia)
```

Estás usando la variable con una lista para dos atributos de ListaSalida. Cuando quieras modificar una lista, se te va a modificar la "otra". Curioso que ponga otra entre comillas, ya que en realidad ambos atributos se refieren al mismo objeto lista. [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/583116/158880) te ayudará a entender mejor.

---

##### Ahora si, la solución

Sabiendo todo esto, debido a que no logro seguir del todo tu código y por que no se puede lograr el objetivo planteado de "trabar" la función, replantee el código. Hice lo que pude para entenderlo, espero que sirva!

```
import tkinter as tk

class Selector(tk.Frame):
    """
    Este es el widget encargado de mostrar los checkbuttons.
    Con el, también es posible obtener que elementos de la lista
    fueron seleccionados.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, lista, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        # Por como está diseñado el código, no necesitamos
        # una lista de checkbuttons
        self.vars = []
        self.lista = lista

        for elemento in lista:
            var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
            self.vars.append(var)

            checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=elemento, variable=var)
            checkbox.pack(pady=1, anchor=tk.W)

    @property
    def selection(self):
        # self.vars[0] se refiere a self.lista[0]
        # self.vars[1] se refiere a self.lista[1]
        # ...
        # Podemos usar zip para iterar ambas listas al mismo tiempo

        return [elemento for var, elemento in zip(self.vars, self.lista) if var.get()]

class DoubleSelector(tk.Frame):
    """
    Esta clase permite seleccionar dos veces.
    La primera seleccion indica que checkboxes aparecerán
    en la segunda.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, lista, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        # contador de selecciones hechas
        self.count = 0

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="seleccione")
        self.label.pack()

        self.selector = Selector(self, lista)
        self.selector.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="continuar", command=self.continuar)
        self.button.pack()

    def continuar(self):
        self.count += 1

        if self.count == 1:
            self.label["text"] = "Seleccione otra vez"

            # Quitamos el primer selector del widget
            self.selector.pack_forget()

            # Creamos un selector cuya lista es la selección del anterior
            self.selector = Selector(self, self.selector.selection)

            # Ubicamos el nuevo selector antes del botón
            self.selector.pack(before=self.button)
        elif self.count == 2:
            self.on_end(self.selector.selection)

    def on_end(self, selection):
        """
        Esta función está destinada a ser ejecutada cuando las
        dos selecciones fueron hechas. Acá podes hacer lo que quieras
        """
        print(selection)


ventana = tk.Tk()

lista = list("abcdefghijk")

selector = DoubleSelector(ventana, lista)
selector.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```